# $L_1$ distance between two Gaussian processes

Tags: gaussian-process, distance-functions

In Brown's famous paper [(1996)](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1032181159), the $L_1$ norm between two Gaussian processes defined on time domain $[0,1]$
$$dY_t = f(t)dt + \sigma(t)dB_t\quad\text{and}\quad
dZ_t = g(t)dt + \sigma(t)dB_t$$
 is given by
$$\|Y_t - Z_t\|_1 = \int\left|\frac{d\mathbb{P}_Y}{d\mathbb{P}_W} - \frac{d\mathbb{P}_Z}{d\mathbb{P}_W}\right| W(d\omega) =  2(1-2\Phi(-D/2)),$$
where $W$ is standard brownian motion and $D = \int (\frac{f(t) - g(t)}{\sigma(t)})^2 dt$.

Although the Radon-Nikodym derivatives are given by Girsanov theorem, I do not see how the second equality is reached.